# 32- or 64-bits float division with PrestoSQL

Tags: sql, numbers, presto, trino

In Presto SQL, `SELECT 1 / 3` returns `0`, because `/` performs integer division.

But `SELECT 1.0 / 3` returns `0.3`... How can I get `0.3333333333`? (i.e., more specifically, 32- or 64-bits precision instead of first decimal truncation?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can `cast()` before dividing.

To get a 64-bit precision:

```
select cast(1 as double) / 3
```

To get a 32-bit precision:

```
select cast(1 as real) / 3
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the literal `1.0` is treated as `DECIMAL(2, 1)`. You could use floating point literals instead:

```
SELECT REAL '1'   / 3 -- '1' is a 32-bit float
SELECT DOUBLE '1' / 3 -- '1' is a 64-bit float
SELECT 1e0        / 3 -- scientific notation implies 64-bit float
```

Comment: I realized we don't currently document the literals, so here's the PR: https://github.com/prestosql/presto/pull/2013

Comment: @piotr that is great. Revised the answer based on the docs (earlier it was just a guess).